# Вывести на экран то число, которое встречается в этой тройке хотя бы два раза

Tags: python

Составить программу, которая вводит с клавиатуры три целых числа a,b,c   и выводит на экран то число, которое встречается в этой тройке хотя бы два раза. Если такого числа нет, программа должна выводить строку “Error”.

```
x = [a, b, c]
dplct = [item for item in set(x) if lst.count(item) > 1]

print(dplct)
```

Comment: Отличное задание. Разрешаю выполнять.

Comment: Ну, у вас почти всё есть. Осталось научиться элементарному - вводить данные с клавиатуры

Comment: Придирки конечно но `Программу, которая вводит с клавиатуры` это очень сложно мб робототехника и тд...  Может Вы имели ввиду что входные данные задает пользователь с клавиатуры? А если серьезно то `lst.count(item)` поменяйте на `x.count(item)` и все заработает..

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
x = [a, b, c]
dplct = [item for item in set(x) if x.count(item) > 1]

if len(dplct) == 0:
    print('Errorr')
else:
    print(dplct[0])
```

:))